# Swift Storyboard Segue Loads Blank View When Called From Closure

Tags: macos, swift, storyboard, closures, segue

If I call the segue from the View Controller's viewWillAppear(), the second view loads as expected
    `performSegueWithIdentifier("CompleteSegue", sender: self)`

But if I perform an async download, and call the segue from inside the success closure, it calls the Segue, runs all the code, and displays the view, but it's completely blank. 
    `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CompleteSegue", sender: self)`

This is an OSX app, and I'm using SwiftHTTP for the download. The Segue type is Sheet.

Comment: All UI changes needs to be on the main thread or it will not update correctly.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how I might get the main threat to act based on something that's happening out of process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grand central dispatch.
In your success closure, do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    // Pseudo code
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CompleteSegue", sender: self) 
});
```

Comment: That did it. I'm new to Swift (and Mac programming), so I suspected the answer was simple and just outside of my experience. Thanks for the easy fix.